# How to correctly poll after WouldBlock?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I am developing Rust Tokio library for ISO-TP. CAN protocol, which lets you send larger messages. The program is aimed towards linux only.

For this, I am using Tokio structure AsyncFd. When the write is called, I create the Future and then poll it. The problem is when I do two consecutive writes, one after the other.

```rust
socket_tx1.write_packet(packet.clone())?.await?;
socket_tx1.write_packet(packet.clone())?.await?;
```

The first write will end successfully, however second will end with

```rust
std::io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock
```

Which is OK and expected. The buffer is full and we should wait until it's clear and ready for the next write. The poll does not guarantee, that if it returns OK, the following write will be successful.

The problem is that I don't know how to handle this behavior correctly.

I tried the following implementations:

```rust
impl Future for IsoTpWriteFuture {
    type Output = io::Result<()>;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        loop {
            let guard = ready!(self.socket.0.poll_write_ready(cx))?;
            match self.socket.0.get_ref().0.write(&self.packet) {
                Err(err) if err.kind() == io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => continue,
                Ok(_) => return Poll::Ready(Ok(())),
                Err(err) => return Poll::Ready(Err(err))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This one works, but after I get WouldBlock, this loop results in busy waiting, which I would like to avoid. Since Socket is ready from poll perspective, write is immediately called, Wouldblock is again returned, and routine spins sometime before resolving the write.

The second implementation is more correct, from my perspective, but it doesn't work right now, and I am not sure how to make it work.

```rust
impl Future for IsoTpWriteFuture {
    type Output = io::Result<()>;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        loop {
            let guard = ready!(self.socket.0.poll_write_ready(cx))?;
            match guard.try_io(|inner|inner.get_ref().0.write(&self.packet)) {
                Err(err) => continue,
                Ok(_) => return Poll::Ready(Ok(())),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work since once try_io() encounters WouldBlock, it will clear readiness from guard. And since poll is edge triggered, this will hang at poll_write_ready and won't make progress.

Is it possible to poll for change after the write returns WouldBlock? Or is the bussy waiting approach unavoidable?

Comment: The "nonblocking sockets" approach always was suspicious to me. As if cutting away a cool feature suddenly makes everything better. The normal way to do it is to have blocking sockets and then use an OS facility (like epoll kqueue etc. or libevent as an abstraction of those) and just let yourself get notified once the socket is ready to take on new data. This mindset also makes me stay away from futures, btw.

Comment: @BitTickler That's a pretty ignorant take on how IO works async/futures work.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Even if there are 1 or 2 use cases out of a 1000 where it might be justified to have a free running loop and waste energy for nothing and heating up our planet, for all the other use cases it is better not to waste do-nohting cpu cycles just to abide the peer pressure and some weird fashion, propagating futures. A classic, blocking event loop is what works best both in terms of efficiency and architecture. While at the same time, the theoretical performance diff does not matter at all.

Comment: @BitTickler If you feel so strongly about it, I suggest writing a blog post. The stack overflow comments section isn't a good place for this.

Comment: @BitTickler Where did you get that futures used a busy loop? They're an abstraction over `epoll`, `kqueue`, etc. just like `libevent` with a nicer syntax.

Comment: @Jmb Unless you do a one time batch kind of job, there is always a thread-specific main loop. In the batch job case, futures might seem elegant, as it looks like linear code, where you can kick off multiple async operations and then only wait for the result once you really need the data. But as soon as you have a thread-loop, futures are not that elegant anymore, because trying to keep  up that style would lead to the thread blocking at more than just 1 point, which quickly can get very confusing and dead-lock-ish. So in my books, futures are quick and dirty tool for batch-job like code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not working due to epoll bug in Linux kernel. I tested it on Kernel 6.6.5 and it was working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In an asynchronous system, after you get a `WouldBlock`, you need to return control to the asynchronous runtime (tokio in this case), as well as tell it what it needs to wait on (the file descriptor being ready).

You say you are using Tokio's [AsyncFd](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/unix/struct.AsyncFd.html). It offers several methods, such as [`poll_read_ready`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/unix/struct.AsyncFd.html#method.poll_read_ready), to check on the fd's readiness and register it with tokio if it needs to wait.

Comment: Well ```let guard = ready!(self.socket.0.poll_write_ready(cx))?;``` is exactly the same as ```poll_read_ready``` only for write readiness. 
The problem is, that write fails, but poll thinks writing is still OK.